# .Less: Using & ampersand in variable name

Tags: css, less

so I was wondering if I could use the parent selector in a list of selectors also in the name of the variable I am using.

So basically I want to go from this:

```
.icon(@color) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: @borderRadius;
  background-color: @color;
}

.in-stock {
  .icon(@inStock-color);
}

.low-stock {
  .icon(@lowStock-color);
}

.out-of-stock {
  .icon(@outOfStock-color);
}

.not-available {
  .icon(@notAvailable-color);
}
```

To this, since the class name and variable names match quite well and it would save code just using the ampersand in the variable name

```
.in-stock,
.low-stock,
.out-of-stock,
.not-available {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: @borderRadius;
  background-color: @&-color;
}
```

Is this possible with .less?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Paste your code into the question. It's much easier for us to help you debug when we can interact with your code, rather than looking a image of it.

Comment: Is better if you add your code into a code snipped instead of using images, follow this link to follow the how to ask a good question guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask